# How to proof a proposition about geometric inequality [solved]

Tags: geometry

When P is a point on the plane where the regular triangle ABC is located and P is not on the outer circle of the regular triangle, then the sum of any two in PA, PB, and PC is greater than the third, that is, they form the three sides of a certain triangle.

If a point C is on one side of perpendicular bisector of line segment AB, assume it biased towards the endpoint A, then line segment CB > CA. So assume point P is located on the outside of line segment AC. In this condition, PB is the longest line segment. Then I considering different situations:

1. PB < AB. In this condition, PA + PC > AC = AB > PB, proofed.
2. PB > AB, and PA >= AB or PC >= AB. In this condition, assume PA < PC, because PA + AB > PB, PC > AB, so PA + PC > PB.
3. PB > AB, and PA < AB and PC < AB. In this condition, I can't proof it.

After Calvin Lin's help, I find then solution.
According to Ptolemy's theorem, In any quadrilateral ABCD, AB·CD + AD·BC >= AC·BD, the equal sign only holds when a quadrilateral is co circular.
So for an equilateral triangle ABC and any point P is not on the outer circle of the regular triangle, we get conclusion AB·PC + BC·PA > AC·PB, then remove equivalency AB, BC, AC because of equilateral triangle and final get PC + PA > PB.
[image]

Comment: Hint: Ptolemy's theorem -> This is how "P is not on the outer circle" applies.

Comment: Thank you Calvin, I suddenly understood

Comment: Can you post your solution then? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I will post solution then.